# podman en windows: conexion al sistema Linux

Tags: windows10, podman

Instale en mi windows 10 podman version 3.4.4.

Al correr en [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) el comando

```
podman -v
```

obtengo

> podman.exe version 3.4.4

pero cuando pongo

```
podman info
```

me da el error

> Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
> Error: unable to connect to Podman socket: Get "http://d/v3.4.4/libpod/_ping": dial unix ///run/podman/podman.sock: connect: An invalid argument was supplied.

dicho comando vi que lo ponen tal cual en el curso [Docker do 0 à Maestria: Contêineres Desmistificados + BÔNUS](https://udemy.com/course/docker-do-zero-a-maestria-conteinerizacao-desmistificada)

Que podre hacer para corregir el error?

### intentos y experimentos

```
podman machine init
```

> Error: unrecognized command `podman.exe machine`
> Try 'podman.exe --help' for more information.

```
 podman.exe --help
```

> Manage pods, containers and images
>
> Usage:   podman.exe [options] [command]
>
> Available Commands:   attach      Attach to a running container
> build       Build an image using instructions from Containerfiles
> commit      Create new image based on the changed container
> container   Manage containers   cp          Copy files/folders between
> a container and the local filesystem   create      Create but do not
> start a container   diff        Display the changes to the object's
> file system   events      Show podman events   exec        Run a
> process in a running container   export      Export container's
> filesystem contents as a tar archive   generate    Generate structured
> data based on containers, pods or volumes   healthcheck Manage health
> checks on containers   help        Help about any command   history
> Show history of a specified image   image       Manage images   images
> List images in local storage   import      Import a tarball to create
> a filesystem image   info        Display podman system information
> init        Initialize one or more containers   inspect     Display
> the configuration of object denoted by ID   kill        Kill one or
> more running containers with a specific signal   load        Load
> image(s) from a tar archive   login       Login to a container
> registry   logout      Logout of a container registry   logs
> Fetch the logs of one or more containers   manifest    Manipulate
> manifest lists and image indexes   network     Manage networks   pause
> Pause all the processes in one or more containers   play        Play
> containers, pods or volumes from a structured file   pod
> Manage pods   port        List port mappings or a specific mapping for
> the container   ps          List containers   pull        Pull an
> image from a registry   push        Push an image to a specified
> destination   rename      Rename an existing container   restart
> Restart one or more containers   rm          Remove one or more
> containers   rmi         Removes one or more images from local storage
> run         Run a command in a new container   save        Save
> image(s) to an archive   search      Search registry for image
> secret      Manage secrets   start       Start one or more containers
> stats       Display a live stream of container resource usage
> statistics   stop        Stop one or more containers   system
> Manage podman   tag         Add an additional name to a local image
> top         Display the running processes of a container   unpause
> Unpause the processes in one or more containers   untag       Remove a
> name from a local image   version     Display the Podman version
> information   volume      Manage volumes   wait        Block on one or
> more containers
>
> Options:   -c, --connection string         Connection to use for
> remote Podman service
> --help                      Help for podman
> --identity string           path to SSH identity file, (CONTAINER_SSHKEY)
> --log-level string          Log messages above specified level (trace, debug, info, warn, warning, error, fatal, panic) (default
> "warn")
> --storage-opt stringArray   Used to pass an option to the storage driver
> --url string                URL to access Podman service (CONTAINER_HOST) (default "unix:/run/podman/podman.sock")   -v,
> --version                   version for podman.exe

Comment: A qué máquina linux le está apuntando tu podman? qué salida obtienes con el comando `podman system connection list` ?

Comment: @Alfabravo no sale nada

Comment: Antón toca `podman machine init` para que le digas a qué linux apuntar. Creo.

Comment: @Alfabravo sale un nuevo error D:=

Comment: Que te dice `Get-Command -All podman` ?

Comment: 'Get-Command' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era un problema de la version de podman, usando la version `4.2.0` aunque aparece el mismo error es posible continuar de la siguiente manera.

Correr

```
podman machine init
```

no importa si tu consola no es de administrador, te abre una de administrador tras confirmar, te instala los elementos faltantes y al terminar te aparece esta consola en la que va a decargar una imagen.
Al terminar de descargar la imagen nos pedira reiniciar.

[image: podman funcionando por priemra vez]